# Django: Call function on form submit

Tags: python, html, django

I have the following issue. I basically want to have a own login page.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')

def login_page(request):
    return render(request, 'home/login.html')

def user_login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        return redirect('/profil/')
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        return redirect('/login/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login/', views.login_page, name='login'),
    url(r'^login/login', views.user_login, name='login_action'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout')
]
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" id="login-page">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form class="form" action="{% url 'login_action' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Benutzername</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Passwort</label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Anmelden</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is now that when I hit the submit button then I land on the page `login/login`, but I am not redirected. I have also tried to add a print statement in the `user_login` method in order to check whether it even reaches that point, but it seems that it does not.

What is my mistake? Thanks for help

Comment: You haven't terminated the "/login/" URL pattern, so "/login/login" matches that. Always terminate the patterns with $.

Comment: Although I can't see why you want two URLs in the first place.

Comment: wow that's embarrassing -.- thank you

Comment: @DanielRoseman how would I do it with one URL?

Comment: Check request.method. if it is GET then return the login page if it is POST then login the user and redirect to profile page